# angular routing with urls starting with # doesnt work

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I want to create routing for angular 2 application with urls starting with #. However, angular redirects to the home page instead of the component. How can I fix this problem?
I used matcher, and it doesn't work.
I use two urls for the same component, but it doesn't work with #. (urls: customcomponent and #/customcomponent). I also tried to use matcher but it also doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Default routing strategy is based on the HTML5 History API, which does not use the '**#**' symbol in the URLs. If you want to use URLs starting with '**#**' in your Angular 2 application, you'll need to configure the routing differently.

You can use the "**HashLocationStrategy**" provided by Angular. This strategy uses the hash symbol '#' in the URLs and enables routing based on the fragment identifier.

In your **app.module.ts**

```
import { LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
  // ...
  providers: [{ provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy }],
  // ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Angular will use the hash symbol in the URLs and handle routing accordingly. For example, #/customcomponent will be recognized as a route to the "CustomComponent".

Once you make this change, Angular will no longer redirect to the home page when using URLs starting with '#'. Instead, it will correctly navigate to the specified component based on the route configuration you have set up.

here some reference link

1. **https://angular.io/api/common/HashLocationStrategy**
2. **https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/angular-location-strategies/**

Hope it helpful..